# Capturing output of remote process from sysinternal's psexec Script

Tags: scripting, deployment, batch, psexec, sysinternals

I'm trying to deploy a program throught PSexec with a script from Bat file to use one CMD instance per computer and not one after the other.

I need a log to be generated on my local server to be sure that the the program succeded succesfully but the generated txt files are empty.

The script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:/temp/computers.csv) do (
  start "%%i" psexec64 \\%%i -d -s cmd /c "msiexec.exe "\\srvname\program.msi"" /Quiet 
)
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much!

---

I tried this way:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:/temp/computers.csv) do (
  start "%%i" psexec64 \\%%i -d -s cmd /c "msiexec.exe "\\folder\prog.msi" /i /quiet /forcerestart" > C:\temp\log-%%i.txt
)
```

My logs files appears, but they're empty.

To be clear, the script open for each computer name its own cmd with an output I want to capture (It tells me if it succeed of failed)

Comment: Specify some of _Logging Options_ for [`msiexec.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/msiexec.html) …

Comment: I tried this way, but id doesn't worked as expected.